# Regex : Prevent a string to end with specif special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using **reactive form validatio**n under my **Angular** app .

i Have a form validation condition which demands that my string didn't end with 
**-** or **'**

i ve tried this , but it seems to not work :

```
Validators.pattern('.*(?<!\-\')$')
```

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `(?<!\-\')` pattern is a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a `-'` substring, while you only want to fail the match if there is either `-` *or* a `'` at the end.

You may use the following solution that uses a *regex literal* notation, so that you didn't have to write a pattern to match the whole input:

```
Validators.pattern(/[^-']$/)
```

Or, if the string can be empty,

```
Validators.pattern(/(?:^|[^-'])$/)
```

The `(?:^|[^-'])$` pattern matches either start of a string (`^`) or any char but a `-` or `'` (with the help of the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), `[^-']`), and `$` asserts the end of the string.